# Calculate the font height from its size in C++?

Tags: c++, fonts, mfc

I am trying to verify the dependency between the `CFont` height and size on an example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int myVariableFontHeight = 90;

  CFont * font = new CFont();

  LOGFONT lf;
  memset(&lf,0,sizeof(LOGFONT));
  lf.lfHeight = myVariableFontHeight;
  lf.lfWeight =FW_BOLD;
  lf.lfCharSet = 1;
  _tcscpy_s(lf.lfFaceName , "Arial Unicode MS");    
  font->CreatePointFontIndirect(&lf);

  font->GetLogFont(&lf);
  int fontHeight = lf.lfHeight;

  HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
  HDC dc = GetDC(console);

  int nFontSize = -::MulDiv( lf.lfHeight, 72, ::GetDeviceCaps( dc, LOGPIXELSY ) );

  delete font;

  return 0;
}
```

And the result is always `nFontSize = myVariableFontHeight/10`. What is this factor 10? Where comes it from? Can I calculate the font height from a given size?

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: In our tool `myVariableFontHeight` had a fix value 90. After I did it configurable I would like to use font sizes like in common text editors. But this var is used multiple in code, so I do not want to break the logic and calc it with myFontSize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the MFC souce code. It's in the documentation.  The very first line of the online documentation for CFont::CreatePointFontIndirect states:

> This function is the same as CreateFontIndirect except that the
>   lfHeight member of the LOGFONT is interpreted in tenths of a point
>   rather than device units.

So, if you want to create a 10 pt font, you set lf.lfHeight to 100.